# java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: invalid DER-encoded certificate data

Tags: java, security, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, keystore

I am getting the  below  exception when I am trying to import the certificate to java keystore.

"java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: invalid DER-encoded certificate data"

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

java.security.cert.CertificateFactory cf = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
            .getInstance("X.509");
while (bis.available() > 0) {
    Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);

    if (cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
            certFx.addCertificate("vel", (X509Certificate) cert, true);
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated !.

Comment: Is the certificate in the correct format?

Comment: yes. It is..@UwePlonus

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you certificate starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ends in `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. Your cert should look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```